# How to construct a char array with absolute integer value(s) and equivalent char integer value(s) in C?

Tags: c++, c, string

For example, I need a char array with contains the `NUL '\0'` character followed by char '1'. Initializing the char array as:

```
char *str = "foo\01bar";
```

result in the following equivalent hex representation:

```
<hex values of foo> 0x1 <hex values of bar>`
```

whereas I require:

```
<hex values of foo> 0x0 <hex value of char '1'> <hex values of bar>
```

How to define such char array (in the `char *str = <mycustomarray>;` way);
I know, that having a modified append routine which also appends the NUL character will do the trick, but I'm not interested in that.

Comment: C does not have a string type. It is all convention. Please consult your C book.

Comment: What language? C or C++?

Comment: C++ is not C is not C++.Pick a language!

Comment: @Olaf True that C does not have a string type, yet does have a _string_ as a special case of character array.

Comment: @chux: This is a normal `char` array as of the C language. the "string" functions of the C stdlib just use a special encoding of the data. The only direct support of the language are _string literals_ which are converted to `(const) char *`.

Comment: Yes, I know C does not have a string type. I meant string not in a C language sense. What I mean is a char array.

Comment: I have reframed the question to remove this ambiguity.

Comment: Note that \01 is declaring a octal value, not two characters.  perhaps you could use: `char *str = {'f', 'o', 'o', '\0', '1', 'b', 'a', 'r', '\0'};`

Comment: @user3629249 Yes, I know this works. I'm interested in the case where we can define it as:
`char *str = <string>;` and not individual fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the C++ Standard:

> octal-escape-sequence:
>   \ octal-digit
>   \ octal-digit octal-digit
>   \ octal-digit octal-digit octal-digit

You can use:

```
char *str = "foo\0001bar";
```

or

```
char *str = "foo\0" "1bar";
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C), the allowed sequences include `\nnn` (octal) and `\xnn` (hex). To  prevent the `1` from being counted as part of the escape sequence, you must fill all digits with zeros, like `\0001` or `\x001`.